# Поиск по тексту и отметка найденных слов

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно сделать поиск по тексту с отметкой всех найденных слов.
Проблема в том, что отмечается первое слово, потом если в тексте есть еще одно совпадение, то отмечается не найденное совпадение а следующее слово.

```
if (textBox2.Text == "")
    MessageBox.Show("Введите текст");

else
{
    string[] words = stroka.Split(new Char[] { ',', ' ', '\n' });
    int index = stroka.IndexOf(textBox2.Text);

    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(words[i]);

        if (words[i] == textBox2.Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Индекс входа " + index.ToString());

            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = index;
            richTextBox1.SelectionLength = textBox2.TextLength;

            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Green;
            MessageBox.Show("Количество символов " + (richTextBox1.SelectionLength).ToString());
            index = richTextBox1.SelectionLength + 1;
        }
    }
}
return stroka;
```

Я не могу понять как написать, чтобы оно брало начальный индекс не со следующего слова, а со следующего совпадения.

Comment: Вы бы код для начала отформатировали как следует.

Comment: Что именно отформатировать ?

Comment: За вас все уже сделали.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Найти следующее вхождение в строку можно используя перегрузку `IndexOf()`, принимающую на вход индекс, с которого нужно начинать поиск:

```
index = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(textBox1.Text, index + textBox1.TextLength);
```

Используйте эту инструкцию вместо вашей:

```
index = richTextBox1.SelectionLength + 1;
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Я исходил из предположения, что `stroka` -- это `richTextBox1.Text`.